# The Bending Moment M of a Beam is given by M=Wx(l-x)/2

Tags: calculus

I have managed to find the maximum bending moment but I am unsure how to find the second derivative to state that it's a maxima. Here is what I have done so far.

$$M= \frac{Wx(l-x)}{2}$$

$$M= \frac{Wxl}{2} -\frac{Wx^2}{2}$$

$$ \frac{dm}{dx} = \frac{Wl}{2} - Wx$$

Turning Points at dm/dx = 0

$$ \frac{Wl}{2} = Wx $$

$$x= \frac{l}{2}$$

Maximum Moment At x=1/2

$$ \frac{W\frac{1}{2}(l-\frac{1}{2})}{2}$$

Maximum moment $$ \frac{Wl^2}{8}$$

How do I determine that this is definitely a maxima? 
How can I ge the second derivative of this?
$$\frac{Wl}{2} - Wx$$

Comment: Please, try to make consitent notations : use $l$ or $L$, $m$ or $M$ but the same everywhere. Thanks.

Comment: To get the second derivative, just take the derivative of the first derivative – that is the second derivative. So, what is the derivative of $\frac{Wl}{2}-Wx$ (with respect to $x$)?

Comment: The second derivative is
$$\frac{d^2m}{dx^2} = \frac{l}{2}-x$$ Is that correct?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct. You differentiated $\frac{Wl}{2}-Wx$ with respect to $W$ there. But you want to differentiate it with respect to $x$.